# Adding foreign disk to Dell Poweredge 2950

Tags: raid, dell, dell-poweredge

I have 4 300G disks in a RAID5 configuration on a Dell Poweredge 2950 with PERC 5/i. I'm trying to replace one of the disks (it failed) with a disk from another identical server.

I got a warning that the disk was foreign, but I cleared the foreign config. Now, however, I can't actually add the new disk to the RAID. It's visible under PDs, but under the VD menu the disk is listed as missing.

How do I get the VD to recognize and add the new disk?

Comment: You may have to do this from within Dell OpenManage in Windows.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Review this question which appears to be similar: http://serverfault.com/questions/338179/dell-poweredge-add-new-disk-to-an-existing-raid-5-array

Comment: I should have specified - I'm running Linux (RHEL 5) on this server, so I'm trying to do this via the RAID utility available with Ctrl-R at boot time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will find that this cannot be done from the RAID utility and must be performed using Dell OpenManage.  If you dont want to install this you can download a LiveCD and boot to it to perform this operation.

http://linux.dell.com/files/openmanage-contributions/

Comment: That did the trick - thank you very much for your help. Next time I'll just rely on hot-swapping and not waste my time trying to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

just for your information, through OpenManage or the RAID utility, CTRL+R, the idea is the same, if the rebuild doesn't starts, assign the disk as a HotSpare and it automatically  will start, it's better if you have OpenManage installed so you don't have to restart the server, clearing the foreign configuration and assigning the disk as a HotSpare can be done with both Utilities.